# Inserting into database gives me "localhost not working"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert information into database through two inputs when you click a submit button. But when I click it it says it can't connect to localhost (everything else works so I know it has to be some form of syntax problem) Code:

```
    <form action="prices.inc.php" method="post">
    <input class="price-list-input" type="text" id="priceupdate1" name="priceupdate1" required></input>
    <input class="price-list-input2" type="text" id="priceupdate2" name="priceupdate2" required></input>
    <input class="price-list-button" type="submit" id="priceupdate-button" name="priceupdate-button" value="Uppdatera"></input>
    </form>
```

the php..

```
<?php

require_once('check_login.inc.php');
    define('SECURE', true);
    require_once('connection.php');


if(isset($_POST['priceupdate-button'])){

    $info = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['priceupdate1'], $_POST['priceupdate2']));

    // prepared statement
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO prices (name, price) VALUES = (?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['priceupdate1'], $_POST['priceupdate2']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($info);

}

?>
```

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $info);` is an error, `ss` means 2 values, as does the `?, ?` but you only pass one, `$info`. Also `id`s and `name`s should be unique. `id="priceupdate"` is present twice. Is `pricupdate` an intentional distinction or a typo?

Comment: you actually get the exact text "localhost not working"?

Comment: Sry should have been more specific. Yeah the "pricupdate" was just a typo, I also tried with different ID's but same result.. @developerwjk the text is "The localhost page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500". Btw what is the right way to add multiple id's inside a $_POST? I tried with an array but same result.

Comment: Okay, well first use distinct ids and names.

Comment: Error 500 means you have an error on the Server. This could be with Apache or with PHP (in some configurations). Chris85 is right in that you have an error in your syntax which could be causing the 500 error

Comment: What is `$_POST[$testarray[0]`? `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['priceupdate1'], $_POST['priceupdate2']);` should work.

Comment: What's inside `check_login.inc.php` and `connection.php`, that's what needs to be known. Your posted code will not produce that error. However, you have a syntax error in here `VALUES = (?, ?)` being the `=` sign; that needs to disappear. You're not connecting with `mysql_` or PDO are you?

Comment: Then you're assigning `$info` first before binding the result. Sorry, but your question's too unclear for me to post an answer for this. Not before I know which animal(s) we're dealing with here exactly.

Comment: There are so many errors in this code. My tip would be to write your PHP one line at a time and test what values you are getting and if it is working properly.

Comment: EDITED the OP.. Yeah I have never tried to update 2 rows in a database with one submit button.. Kind of lost :S

Comment: GOT IT WORKING.. all that was the problem was the "=" that @Fred-ii- mentioned.. Jesus christ

Comment: @Chumppe I posted a community wiki answer below that you can mark as solved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you

Comment: I noticed the edit. I did a rollback to a previous revision. Just mark the question as solved from the answer I gave you below and the link I gave you then come back to the answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/39781883/1415724

Comment: @chris85 It was the `=` sign that killed it. I posted a community wiki answer below and as per [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781490/inserting-into-database-gives-me-localhost-not-working#comment66857677_39781490) I left up there. I'm kind of surprised you didn't pick up on that ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha, I saw 4 errors prior to looking at the actual query.

Comment: @chris85 True and you had the "Eagle eye" there. Yet, that `=` sign was in there from "the get go" http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39781490/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *GOT IT WORKING.. all that was the problem was the "=" that @Fred-ii- mentioned.. – Chumppe*

Posting as a community wiki. I don't want rep for this but just to close the question.

[As I said in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781490/inserting-into-database-gives-me-localhost-not-working/39781883#comment66857677_39781490), `VALUES = (?, ?)` the equal sign shouldn't be there.

Example from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO City (District) VALUES (?)");
```